# Accessing correct preference value in onsyncfrompreference after preference.reset()

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I want to have a "Restore defaults" button in my extension's preferences window:

```
<prefpane id="nextplease.phrases" label="&options.phrases.title;"
          image="chrome://nextplease/skin/Document.png">
    <preferences>
        <preference id="nextphrases" name="nextplease.nextphrase.expr0"
                    type="unichar"/>
        ...
    </preferences>
    <hbox flex="1">
        ...
                <listbox id="nextphrases_list" seltype="multiple" flex="1"
                    onkeypress="nextplease.removeSelectedOnDelete(event, this);"
                    onselect="nextplease.enableDisableRemoveButton(this);" 
                    preference="nextphrases" preference-editable="true" 
                    onsynctopreference="return nextplease.syncListbox(this);" 
                    onsyncfrompreference="nextplease.loadListboxPreference(this);"/>
                ...
                <button label="&options.restoreDefault;"
                    oncommand="nextplease.restoreDefaultListbox(this);" />
            </hbox>
        </vbox>
    </hbox>
</prefpane>
```

This is the JavaScript code for the functions:

```
nextplease.restoreDefaultListbox = function (node) {
    var listbox = node.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.selectedPanel;
    var preferenceId = listbox.getAttribute("preference");
    var preference = document.getElementById(preferenceId);
    preference.reset();
    alert("preference.value="+preference.value+"; preference.valueFromPreferences="+preference.valueFromPreferences);
    preference.setElementValue(listbox);
};

nextplease.loadListboxPreference = function (listbox) {
    var i, phrase, values;

    var preferenceId = listbox.getAttribute("preference");
    var preference = document.getElementById(preferenceId);
    var prefValue = ??? // neither preference.value nor preference.valueFromPreferences work, see below
    // alert("Loading: "+prefValue);

    // remove all items already in listbox
    for (i = listbox.itemCount; i >= 0; i--) {
        listbox.removeItemAt(i);
    }

    values = prefValue.split("|");
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        phrase = values[i].replace(/&pipe;/g, "|");
        if (phrase !== "") {
            listbox.appendItem(phrase, phrase);

            // Scroll to the newly added item to workaround 
            // what I think is a Firefox bug. I was getting
            // Javascript exceptions when trying to read the
            // values at the bottom that are "hidden".
            listbox.ensureIndexIsVisible(listbox.getRowCount() - 1);
        }
    }
    listbox.ensureIndexIsVisible(0);
};
```

Now, when I click on the button, the alert I get (after `preference.reset()`) looks like this:

> preference.value=undefined; preference.valueFromPreferences=old user-set preference value

So it seems like in onsyncfrompreference the correct preference value can't be accessed except in a really ugly way:

```
if (preference.value === undefined) {
  prefValue = preference.preferences.defaultBranch.getIntValue(preference.name); // or other type instead of Int
} else {
  prefValue = preference.value;
}
```

Is there a better alternative? Specifically, one which would work for any preference type?

Comment: Is this question different than your previous one? If not you should edit your previous question and maybe add a bounty.

Comment: Yes, it's different. This problem 1) only appears when restoring default values (which aren't involved in that question at all); 2) with the other direction of synchronization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [pref.value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/preference#p-value) === `undefined`, you should use `pref.defaultValue` to get the value to display. I updated the reference page and [the onsyncfrompreference documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Preferences_System/New_attributes#onsyncfrompreference.2fonsynctopreference) to say that.

Comment: Ah, so it does have a `defaultValue` property! Nice. I can get rid of my workaround now...